# What's the name of signal encoding used by WS2812 LEDs?

Tags: modulation, digital-modulation, ws2812b

The WS2812b color LED uses some kind of duty cycle encoding to encode three states:

- one
- zero
- reset

This can be seen in the following figure:
[image: WS2812 Protocol]

(Source: https://cpldcpu.files.wordpress.com/2014/01/ws2812_protocol.png)

What's the name of the used encoding?

It's not classic Pulse Width Modulation (PWM).

**Edit:**
While this question [What encoding is used in this signal?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/145714/what-encoding-is-used-in-this-signal) asks for a name of a similar modulation, it does not give a name for the modulation.

Comment: Looks to be just a made up one.  Not unusual to have a sync pattern then some data.  You see similar ones used elsewhere, not having a global name either.

Answer (score 7):

AFAIK it doesn't have a fixed name, apart from 'the WS2812 protocol'. As described, it is a fixed-cell pulse-width encoding.

FYI: in practice, it isn't fixed-cell at all: provided that the pauses (T1L, T0L) are shorter than Treset, all that matters is the pulse width (T0H, T1H). This makes it a plain pulse-wdith encoding, and it makes bit-banging waaaaay easier.

Comment: This looks like a variant of 1-wire protocol encoding scheme, also referred as "PWM", in this case it looks like 33/66% PWM. The protocol was invented by Dallas Semiconductor, now a part of MAXIM.


   http://home.roboticlab.eu/en/examples/sensor/1-wire

Comment: I don't see what this unidirectional protocol has to do with the bi-directional dallas/maxim 1-wire protocol. And IMO PWM is a strange term to describe this protocol, because it isn't a Modulation, it is an Encoding. So yes, it is a pulse-width encodong, just like 1-wire, and dozens of others.

Answer (score 1):

This is what World-Semi calls it, they make the WS2812B

> The data transfer protocol use single NZR communication mode. After the pixel power-on reset, the DIN
>   port receive data from controller, the first pixel collect initial 24bit data then sent to the internal data latch,
>   the other data which reshaping by the internal signal reshaping amplification circuit sent to the next cascade
>   pixel through the DO port. After transmission for each pixel，the signal to reduce 24bit. pixel adopt auto resha
>   -ping transmit technology, making the pixel cascade number is not limited the signal transmission, only depend
>   on the speed of signal transmission.

Comment: This does not answer my question. I asked for the signal modulation name, but not how communication works.

Comment: The question was "What's the name of the used encoding?"  The manufacturer calls it "single NZR communication mode".  I think that does answer the question.

Comment: I get your point, but I believe this is a typo. There is no `NZR` code (according to Google), but `NRZ` (Non-Return to Zero`). NRZ is a general term and the basis for many codes.

Comment: Next suggestion would be to browse the Adafruit Neopixel library of the FastLED.h library and see if they call it something else.